# how to refactor this page so it is responsive with ipad dimensions

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a landing page I need to fix and I am quite rusty on css. Currently I have a layout and there are a lot of fixed widths and absolute positioning which I know is problematic when trying to create a responsive layout. I need this same layout but to be responsive and change accordingly to ipad dimensions as it is currently static.

I know I need to use %'s for the height and width instead of these fixed values, but do I also need to use relative units like rems? Here is what the page should look like at and be responsive at all times.

[image]

Here is my current markup for this page and css.

Index

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="globals.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="landing-page">
      <div class="div">
        <div class="overlap">
          <div class="ava-logo">
            <div class="overlap-group">
              <div class="frame"><img class="logo" src="img/logo-64.png" /></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <img class="helo-ava-label" src="img/heloavalabel.svg" />
          <div class="text-wrapper">Text here</div>
        </div>
        <div class="register-button-wrapper">
          <div class="register-button"><div class="text-wrapper-2">Button</div></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

css

```
.landing-page {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.landing-page .div {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 1440px;
  height: 1024px;
  position: relative;
}

.landing-page .overlap {
  position: absolute;
  width: 544px;
  height: 1031px;
  top: -7px;
  left: 896px;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgb(26, 179, 116) 0%, rgb(0, 122, 195) 100%);
}

.landing-page .ava-logo {
  position: absolute;
  width: 326px;
  height: 339px;
  top: 283px;
  left: 97px;
  border-radius: 162.95px/169.7px;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgb(26, 179, 116) 0%, rgb(0, 122, 195) 93.75%);
}

.landing-page .overlap-group {
  position: relative;
  width: 214px;
  height: 210px;
  top: 71px;
  left: 56px;
  background-image: url(./img/union.svg);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.landing-page .frame {
  position: relative;
  width: 84px;
  height: 84px;
  top: 56px;
  left: 65px;
}

.landing-page .logo {
  position: absolute;
  width: 84px;
  height: 82px;
  top: 1px;
  left: 0;
}

.landing-page .helo-ava-label {
  position: absolute;
  width: 365px;
  height: 120px;
  top: 787px;
  left: 92px;
}

.landing-page .text-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  width: 255px;
  top: 138px;
  left: 138px;
  font-family: "Inter", Helvetica;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 32px;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  line-height: normal;
}

.landing-page .register-button-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  width: 896px;
  height: 1024px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-image: url(./img/rectangle-64.png);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.landing-page .register-button {
  display: flex;
  width: 431px;
  height: 74px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 10px 51px;
  position: relative;
  top: 862px;
  left: 220px;
  background-color: #027dbe;
  border-radius: 27px;
}

.landing-page .text-wrapper-2 {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  font-family: "Poppins", Helvetica;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 32px;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  line-height: normal;
}

/* For iPad portrait mode */
@media (max-width: 768px) {}
```

Comment: You MAY consider `vw`. Because that you can apply to the font too. 

Comment: What do you want it to look like in portrait mode?

Comment: Just the same exact way, right now its not scaling properly. If i go to iPad dimensions then its just in that fixed static position and i can see only the top-left of the placeholder image @AHaworth

Comment: Use %s. I don’t think there’s anything suitably relative about rems.

Comment: So what would be best practice in this scenario. I change all the measure from px to %'s?  even the absolute positioning of the button, etc? or is there a better way to do it? @AHaworth

Comment: Not certain what everyone might call 'best practice' but I'd consider using a CSS grid.

Answer (score 1):

in order to create responsive design with css, you need to use css @media Rule.

---

**@Media** queries can be used to check many things, such as:

- width and height of the viewport
- width and height of the device
- orientation

For eaxmple:

If you want to apply css rules to screens that are less than 600px width you would use:

```
    @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
        body {background-color: lightblue;}
    }
```

And for the screens that are 600px and more:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
            body {background-color: lightblue;}
        }
```

- [Check this W3 guide](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.php)

Comment: The OP wants the same sort of layout whatever the viewport dimensions/aspect ratio so I don’t see that media queries would help.